# Segmentation Fault ( core dumped) even though all pointers are fine

Tags: segmentation-fault, palindrome, coredump

I'm trying to implement a program which checks whether a sentence is a palindrome or not. Using Turbo C/C++, it gives me the correct output each time, but on exit from main() program it either gives "DIVIDE ERROR" or goes into an infinite loop sometimes. When i tried with an online compiler it returns "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)". Any ideas? I traced the entire program and all the pointers are fine.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char *p1,*p2,*temp;
 int spcount=0,flag=0;
 float sp;
 printf("\nEnter string\n");
 cin.getline(p1,1000,'\n');
 temp=p1;
 while(*temp!='\0')
  if(*(temp++)==' ')
   spcount++;
 p2=--temp;
 printf("\nSpace Count is %d",spcount);
 sp=((float)spcount+1.0)/2.0;
 while(sp-->0)
 {
  while(*p2!=' ')
    p2--;
  p2++;
  while(*p1!=' ')
  {
    if(*p1!=*p2)
     flag=1;
    p1++;
    p2++;
  }
  p1++;
  p2--;
  while(*p2!=' ')
   p2--;
  p2--;
 }
 if(flag==0)
  printf("PALINDROME");
 else
  printf("NOT A PALINDROME");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to think, that all pointers are fine? Have your tried to use debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration for p1 creates a pointer variable but does not allocates an array/buffer for it to point to. So there is no room to store a string to it and besides, it is uninitialized, so could point anywhere.

```
char *p1,*p2,*temp; // just pointers, no space, p1 could point to anywhere
```

The cin.getline writes into nothing

```
cin.getline(p1,1000,'\n'); // where is p1 pointing to?
```

Try instead:

```
char buf[1000];
char *p1 = buf;
```

Odd that you say all pointers are fine, when the first error I see is erroneous pointers. Maybe a refresher on pointers would help you. Pointers have to point to valid memory with space to store things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew I was missing something but as the program ran fine giving the correct output in Turbo C/C++, I couldn't identify the problem. I should be learning from these mistakes. I'm a beginner.